# Rails_admin show text written by CKEditor with html format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, rails-admin

I have integrated CKEditor for my rails_admin. In `edit` page I have added CKEditor and wrote text.

In my model showing page it shows me like that:
[image]

My code for `show`:

```
show do
  include_all_fields

end
```

What I need to add, to show my text, written on CKEditor, able to show in rails_admin?

**==== UPDATE ====**

I have added `config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )` code in my `production.rb and development.rb`. Then I have run rake assets precompile tasks and restarted my server. It still shows the same thing in my image above.

Even If it will be possible to show text in html format, it will born new question. As you can see in image, there is `img` tag and its `src` shows not full directory of my uploaded image. If I need to send this formatted text as JSON to my phone?

**==== UPDATE ====**

I have opened code inspector of my browser to see `description` part of my page. It showd me this:
[image: browsers code inspector]

My html code, created by CKEditor, is written well, but my browser does not consider it as html code and there is quotation marks. Does these quotation marks affect to my browser to show it as bare text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found solution. I don't know is it good or not:

```
show do
  include_all_fields

  field :description do
    pretty_value do
      value.html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your CKEditor config `startupMode` is settled as 'source'. Remove that if so.

Comment: In my `ckeditor.rb` in my config, there is no `startupMode` is written

Answer (score 0):

During asset precompilation Ckeditor gem would compile the source from vendor/assets/ckeditor folder into the special resource package that looked like this:

```
$ ls public/assets/ckeditor/
application.js
application.js.gz
application-1f3fd70816d8a061d7b04d29f1e369cd.js
application-1f3fd70816d8a061d7b04d29f1e369cd.js.gz
application-450040973e510dd5062f8431400937f4.css
application-450040973e510dd5062f8431400937f4.css.gz
application.css
application.css.gz
ckeditor-b7995683312f8b17684b09fd0b139241.pack
ckeditor.pack
filebrowser
images
plugins
skins
lang
```

and, apparently, plain `ckeditor.js` was just not there. In order to provide the necessary source files I had to explicitly add them to the precompile array for the production environment in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
> config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )
```

Then `run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: I thought I needed to add `config/initializers/assets.rb` this code, according to this https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#deployment

Comment: As you instructed, I have added `config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/* )` in my `production.rb` and `development.rb` then run `run rake assets:precompile`. It created a lot of files (A LOT OF FILES) in my `public/ckeditor` folder. It still shows bare `html code` in my show page.

Comment: Have you rebooted your server rails ?

Comment: I have done all things that you wrote and rebooted my server. It still shows bare html code inside my one model showing page in rails_admin

Comment: Maybe I need to write some thing like that: `field :description do #some code end`, but I don't know what to add.

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution and for me it's working fine:

make that your config/initializers/rails_admin.rb

```
config.model Post do
    edit do
      field :title, :text do 
        label 'title'
      end
      field :content, :ck_editor, :text do
        label 'content'
      end
    end
  end
```

and your index/show

```
<%= raw @post.content %>
```